# How to close a modal window clicking outside in React + Redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, modal-window

Making an application (react + redux). It contains a few photos. When you click a photo you get a modal window with bigger photo and comments.

Code for ModalContainer (contains modal window itself):

```
class ModalContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    comment: '',
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { isOpen, closeModal } = this.props
    if (isOpen) {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', closeModal)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const { closeModal } = this.props
    document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'
    document.removeEventListener('click', closeModal)
  }

  inputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    })
  }

  putComment = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const { comment, name } = this.state
    const { photo } = this.props
    axios
      .post(
        `https://boiling-refuge-66454.herokuapp.com/images/${photo.id}/comments`,
        { name: name, comment: comment, date: Date.parse(String(new Date())) }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
      })
    this.setState({
      name: '',
      comment: '',
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { name, comment } = this.state
    const { closeModal, photo } = this.props
    const comments = photo.comments
    return (
      <>
        <Modal
          onClick={closeModal}
          src={photo.url}
          comments={comments}
          name={name}
          comment={comment}
          onChange={this.inputChange}
          onSubmit={this.putComment}
        />
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  ({ modal }) => ({
    photo: modal.photo,
    isOpen: modal.isOpen,
  }),
  { closeModal }
)(ModalContainer)
```

As you can see I have this code `document.addEventListener('click', closeModal)` inside `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method.  Brackets contains action creator `closeModal`, which closes my modal. In that case it doesn't work correctly because it launches action creator even if I click inside my modal. So I can't add comment inside.

In this case, what is the proper way to close a modal window by clicking outside a window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common practice is to wrap `Modal` in an `ModalOverlay`,

style `ModalOverlay` to be full screen.

```js
function onOverlayClick(e) {
  closeModal()
  e.stopPropagation()
}

function onModalClick(e) {
  // need to stop propagation to ModalOverlay onClick event
  e.stopPropagation()
}

return (
      <div className="full-screen" onClick={onOverlayClick}>
        <Modal
          onClick={onModalClick}
          src={photo.url}
          comments={comments}
          name={name}
          comment={comment}
          onChange={this.inputChange}
          onSubmit={this.putComment}
        />
      <div/>
    )
```

Comment: so, what to return in `ModalOverlay`?

Comment: ModalOverlay is a styled element. You can replace it with `<div>`

Answer (score 2):

if `Modal` is a class component you can add `ref` to it (if it's a function component use `fowardRef`)

```
<Modal ref={modalNode => (this.modalNode = modalNode)}
```

and adapt your eventListener

```
handleClick = e => !this.modalNode.contains(e.target) && closeModal();

 componentDidMount() {
    const { isOpen, closeModal } = this.props
    if (isOpen) {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick)
  }
```